# Best way to submit/redirect a html form to validation.php securly with a csp header?

Tags: php, html, forms, security, content-security-policy

I made a HTML form with a php csp header. I want to make a safe checkout with php. My csp header looks like this:  `Content-Security-Policy:default-src 'none'; base-uri 'self'; form-action 'none' https:example.com;`. My form has also a php generated CSRF token.

Now my problem: I have a **index.php** file with the form and the token generator, a **validation.php** file and a **thankyou.php** file with the end screen. I want that the **validation.php** file not display in the url when redirect to the **thankyou.php** file.

**index.php**

```
<!---- HERE IS MY PHP CODE ---->
header('X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block');
header('X-Frame-Options: deny');
header('X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff');
header('Referrer-Policy: same-origin');
/* CSRF Protection */
$_SESSION['token'] = bin2hex(random_bytes(24));
<!---- ******************* ---->
<form id="delivery-form" action="php/validation.php"> <!---- HERE I'M NOT SURE HOW TO HIDE ---->
    <div id="delivery-address" class="site">
    <h2>Delivery Address/h2>

    <!---Radio Buttons---->
    <label for="men" class="radio men">
        <input type="radio" name="rdo" id="men" class="hidden"/>
        <span class="label"></span>Herr
    </label>
  
    <label for="woman" class="radio">
        <input type="radio" name="rdo" id="woman" class="hidden"/>
        <span class="label"></span>Frau
    </label><br><br>
  
    <div class="inputBox">
        <input type="text" placeholder=" " name="firstname" autocomplete="on" required value="">
        <label>Firstname</label>
    </div><br>

    <div class="inputBox">
        <input type="text" placeholder=" " name="lastname" class="big_break" autocomplete="on" required value="">
        <label>Lastname</label>
    </div><br>
    
    <div class="inputBox">
        <input type="text" placeholder=" " name="street" id="input_middle_size" autocomplete="on" required value="">
        <label>Street</label>
    </div>
    <div class="inputBox">
        <input type="text" placeholder=" " name="number" id="input_small_size" autocomplete="on" required value="">
        <label>Number</label>
    </div><br>
    
    <div class="inputBox">
        <input type="text" placeholder=" " name="plz" id="input_small_size" autocomplete="on" required value="">
        <label>Place</label>
    </div>
    <div class="inputBox">
        <input type="text" placeholder=" " name="town" class="big_break" id="input_middle_size" autocomplete="on" required value="">
        <label>town</label>
    </div><br>

    <div class="inputBox">
        <input type="email" placeholder=" " name="email" autocomplete="on" required value="">
        <label>E-Mail</label>
    </div><br>
    <!---Vorwahl und Telefonnummer Feld---->
    <div class="inputBox">
        <input type="text" placeholder=" " name="vorwahl" id="input_small_size" autocomplete="on" required value="">
        <label>area-code</label>
    </div>
    <div class="inputBox">
        <input type="tel" placeholder=" " name="phone_number" class="big_break" id="input_middle_size" autocomplete="on" required value="">
        <label>phone-number</label>
    </div><br>
   </div>
</form>
```

Because hacker can then attack my **validation.php** file. I read an article over [Post/Redirect/Get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
But I have no idee, how I can redirect securly.

I hope anyone can tell me how I can redirect from my form to the validation.php and thankyou.php file (Mostly Hacker Safe).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway you have to send form somewhere to the server, and you can not hide this PHP-module by redirects (these easily trace in HTTP headers so it's protection from the kiddie-hackers only).

You already do use CSRF token and CSP's `form-action` for security. That's good.
To complicate hackers attacks you can additionally use CAPTCHA service (like reCAPTHA, hCAPTCHA), but these third-party scripts required to be also allowed in CSP (since you use it).

But it's impossible to hide a form handler (**validation.php** in your case).
It's only possible to create validation.php handler with no vulnerabilities and leave hackers no chances.